# CSS Flex stretch not working together with vertical align

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a simple menu bar with CSS flexbox. My menu buttons use `stretch` so that the buttons are the same height as the menu bar.

The problem is that the text inside the buttons is not centered vertically if one of the divs is taller than the others.

I have tried using `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center`. While that centers the content, the buttons don't stretch to the same height as their parent anymore, which looks ugly when hovering over the divs :(

Can my flex children stretch vertically AND have their contents centered vertically?

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div><img src="./largelogo.png"></div>      // a tall div
    <div>Artists</div>                          // should stretch AND center
    <div>Playlists</div>
    <div>Genres</div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #60B99A;
  color:white;
}

nav div:hover {
    color: #60B99A;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Add the same flex code on the nav to the child divs.

Answer (score 1):

If you also make the inner `div`'s a flex container, you can center their text/content vertically.

Stack snippet

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: stretch;              stretch is default, so this is not needed  */
  justify-content: center;
  background: #60B99A;
  color:white;
}

nav div {
  display: flex;                   /*  added  */
  align-items: center;             /*  added  */
}

nav div:hover {
  color: #60B99A;
  background: white;
}

nav div img {
  display: block;                  /*  remove the bottom white space  */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/f00"></div>      
    <div>Artists</div>                          
    <div>Playlists</div>
    <div>Genres</div>
</nav>
```

---

And for anyone who want the inner `div` themselves to be centered, use `align-items: center`.

Stack snippet

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;             /*  changed  */
  justify-content: center;
  background: #60B99A;
  color:white;
}

nav div:hover {
    color: #60B99A;
    background: white;
}

nav div img {
  display: block;                  /*  remove the bottom white space  */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/f00"></div>      
    <div>Artists</div>                          
    <div>Playlists</div>
    <div>Genres</div>
</nav>
```